# ERROR: array value must start with "{" or dimension information LINE 1

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sql-insert

When I run the code it shows me this error.

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number:

ERROR: array value must start with "{" or dimension information LINE 1: ...0232882', 'Kathmandu', 'Baneshwor', '2016-06-08', '13:00', '... ^

INSERT INTO "report" ("ukey", "district", "police_station", "event_date", "event_time", "accident_severity", "hit_and_run", "report_recorded_timestamp", "no_vechiles_involved", "no_of_driver_casualty", "no_of_passenger_casualty", "no_of_pedestrian_casualty") VALUES ('57567b4729356260232882', 'Kathmandu', 'Baneshwor', '2016-06-08', '13:00', '3', 'false', '2016-06-07 09:44:26', '1', '1', '0', '0')

Filename: C:\wamp\www\nrcds\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

I dont know whats wrong. Please guide me. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the error is clear, add brackets on the value of the `array column`

Comment: if `accident_severity` is of type `array` then instead of `3` should be smth like `[3]` or alike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your columns is an array. Add `{}` around the column.

```
INSERT INTO "report" (yourarraycolumn) VALUES ('{value}')
```